# Python: If directory exist then return its content to another directory

Tags: python, zip

I'm looking for a directory in directory if found and then returning its content to some destination directory:

So far:

```
import os
for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for filename in files:
        fname = os.path.join(dirpath,filename)
        if dirpath.endswith('3'):
            if lst == '3':
                #glob('path_to/*/3')
                os.rename('dirpath',  '/Destination_path/3')
                print(fname)
                print(True)
```

Example: I'm looking for directories named as 3 in a huge list of directory and return its content to a destination.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: `os.rename('dirpath',` ?? And be careful when renaming directories while walking through them. and what is your question?

Comment: I'm a newbie, So how to do this?

Comment: Basically I' m trying to unzip a file and search a directory and if directory found, move its content to another directory. Thanks in advance.